# Android mvvm livedata and databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am experimenting the new architecture components from Google trying to achieve more reactive code using `ViewModel`, `LiveData` and `DataBinding`.

Basically my idea around `ViewModel` is to have only one field of type `Model`(user for the record since we are representing a user profile scree). So my `ViewModel` class is :

```
class ViewModel : ViewModel() {

var model = MutableLiveData<User>()
```

and my `Model` class is :

```
class User(var name: String, var lastName: String, var age: Int)
```

In my layout file, I am trying to bind the fields on my `Model` into the view using `DataBinding` plugin. The problem is that since my `ViewModel` has a `MutableLiveData<User>` I can't access (from xml binding) the fields inside the `User` class (name, lastName...).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.github.andromedcodes.mvvmtutorial.ViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@{viewModel.user.name}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Is it even possible to do that? And which is better, having a `ViewModel` with separate Fields (String, Int, Whatever...) or re-using a `Model`?

Comment: you should be able to access those fields on your xml layout. are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes i get a data accessor error when i write something like 
android:text="@{viewModel.user.name}"

Comment: can you paste your xml layout here? are you declaring your viewmodel under the <data> element?

Comment: Absolutely! all the variables are under <data> tag. I will edit my post with my xml layout.

Comment: from your view model code, i think you should have `android:text="@{viewModel.model.name}"` (or change `model` on your `ViewModel` to `user`)

Comment: That's correct. All the issue was the field name in xml not matching the ViewModel field name. Thanks a lot @takecare !

Comment: By the way, Which is better? Having the data inside model classes or exploding them into fields in ViewModel?

Comment: in my opinion you're better off just having the view model and using it in your layout (it's a view model after all). pretty much what you already have.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for your help @takecare

Answer (score 0):

You can see my repository where I did everything using DataBinding and MVVM pattern . Just visit https://github.com/xyarim/android-architecture